# Lucene: Center highlighted words in a fragment

Tags: java, lucene

Is there a way to have the same amount of text before and after a highlighted word, if possible, with Lucene highlighter?

Currently I have this:

```
QueryScorer queryScorer = new QueryScorer(query, field);
Fragmenter fragmenter = new SimpleSpanFragmenter(queryScorer, frag_lenth);
SimpleHTMLFormatter htmlFormatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter("<<<<",">>>>");
Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(htmlFormatter, queryScorer);
highlighter.setTextFragmenter(fragmenter); 
String text = doc.get(field);
TokenStream tokenStream = TokenSources.getAnyTokenStream(searcher.getIndexReader(), id, field, analyzer);
String high = highlighter.getBestFragments(tokenStream, text, limit_frag, " ..... ");</code>
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: not very much. i adjusted fragment size to get more text than needed so i can parse it and somehow extract what i need, but there are still cases where there is not enough text after a highlighted word. It sounds kind of shade but i'm new and this is for a school project.